# ALFA AWUS036NH not connecting to kali linux on virtual box

Tags: kali-linux

my alfa awus036nh is not connecting to kali linux on a virtual box, but it works fine with host os. I had exchanged Panda PAU06 for this one with the assumption that something is wrong with the former one but now same issue with this. Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

Download and install VirtualBox extension pack.
You can download it from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Make sure the extension pack you are installing is of same version with your Virtual Box.